# keras limit the values of the output layer to a vector of values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have the array `X` input as:

```
[[12,13,14],
..........
[32,15,19],
[23,16,17]
]
```

My output `y` as:

```
[[5]
..........
[7],
[9]
]
```

I'm sure that y in all cases takes values ONLY 5,7,9

Can someone tell me which model is best for me to use.
At the moment I have used:

```
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(len(sequence)*10, input_shape=(len(sequence),), activation='relu')) 
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu')) 
  model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

Then when I fit:

```
yhat1 = md1.predict(xCheck)
```

I get the output as 3, 5, 11 which doesn't suit me.

Comment: if you have fixed outputs, create a classifier with 3 outputs representing one-hot value of 5,7,9

Comment: i'm undestend my bad model. how change?

Comment: instead of `model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu')) ` use `model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax')) ` and change you y labels in [one hot format](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/)

Comment: no output is 7 or 5 or 9 ==== 1 number ! not array.  but have 9 or 5 or 7

Comment: Im sorry, I can't understand what you are saying. You will have to pick the highest output out of 3, look more into "classification with neural nets". if the 1st value in array is highest, the output is 5, if the second value is highest, the output is 7, if the last is highest, the output is 9

Comment: yes i can do it
but when I feed data for prediction, I get an incorrect prediction.
I would like to change the model so that it cuts out already guaranteed incorrect data inside.

conditionally

5 7 9

model inside showed 4.9 == int (4.9) == 5 true

model inside showed 14.9 == int (14.9) == 15 false